# How can I inherit all properties from all Base classes in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, multiple-inheritance, xna-4.0

I have XNA game and it contains these classes

```
public partial class Bird : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
{
    private Vector2 velocity;
    private Vector2 position;
    ..........................
    public Vector2 Velocity
    {
        get { return velocity; }
        set { velocity = value; }
    }
    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }

}
public class BigRedBird : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent,Bird
{

    public BigRedBird(Game game ,Rectangle area,Texture2D image)
        : base(game)
    {
        // TODO: Construct any child components here

    }
    .....................
}
```

How can I access Position and velocity from Bird Class and use it in BigRedBird Class in the
constructor.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with you are inheriting from two classes which would be illegal.

As Bird already inherits from GameComponent its not a problem that you don't mention it in BigRedBird it's already inherited through bird!

As BigRedBird inherits from Bird it will have all its properties so you just need to do

```
public class BigRedBird : Bird 
{ 

    public BigRedBird(Game game ,Rectangle area,Texture2D image) 
        : base(game) 
    { 
        // TODO: Construct any child components here 
        this.Position= ....

    } 
    ..................... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, so the answer to the question in your title is - you can't.  But I don't think that's what you were trying to achieve.

Add suitable constructors to your Bird class:

```
public partial class Bird : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameComponent
{
   public Bird( Game game ) : base(game)
   {
   }

   public Bird( Game game, Vector2 velocity, Vector2 position ) : base(game)
   {
       Velocity = velocity;
       ...
   }
}
```

And then call the base class constructor in your derived class

```
public class BigRedBird : Bird
{
    public BigRedBird( Game game, ... ) : base(game, ... )
    {
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class BigRedBird : Bird
{
    public BigRedBird( Game game, ... ) : base(game)
    {
        base.Velocity = ...;  // note: base. not strictly required
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inherit `BigRedBird` from `Bird` only. By doing that, you will still be able to access stuff from `GameComponent`, since `Bird` inherits from it.

By the way, inheriting from multiple classes is not possible in C#.